How to warp/distort text to random axonometry?
I am drawing something in random axonometry. There is no problem drawing geometric shapes since I made a template grid to match all the lines. Now I would like to add some text and I don't get the result I want (see the attached screenshot). I tried 3D rotate, envelope warp (mesh) and it just doesn't seem to work the way I want. The closest I can get to is free distort, but there are no anchors to snap to so it's kinda hard to match the angles. Also I would have to do this to every single letter/word which is very time consuming and only approximately correct.
Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!



Here's a solution that leaves the text editable, so that the process doesn't become time-consuming:

Create a short text
Apply a rotation using Effects > Distort & Transform > Transform with an angle around -15°.
Go to Object > Transform > Shear and use a shear angle of nearly 30°.

To find the exact angles, there are two options:

either you first try this technique on a rectangle and find approximate angles such that the rectangle is accurately aligned with your grid;
or you know the axonometric parameters from which the angles can be computed, typically if the projection is isometric.

I applied this method using the picture from the original post as a background, with rotation angle -16° and shear angle 30°:

This is not perfect since Illustrator doesn't include the shear transform as an editable effect (see also this discussion), which makes the approximation of the angle and ulterior modifications less easy.
Nonetheless, the text remain fully editable and the framebox can be elongated, allowing you to duplicate the object for all the other texts. I hope this will be sufficient for your work!

This is achievable with the Classic 3D rotate effect.

Type out a piece of text;
Select the text object;
Choose Effect > 3D and Materials > 3D (Classic) > Rotate (Classic)...
Choose a custom rotation at 50°, 32°, and -16.5° (in that order) for the three axes. Leave perspective at 0°.

This can be applied to live text, and the text will stay rotated exactly to your grid. I found the values by trial and error, and thus they are off by a few tenths of degrees. So, for longer texts or bigger objects, there will be some slight deviation. But for short texts and small objects, it should be good enough.
You can turn the effect in to Graphic Style to easily appy it to multiple objects:

Open the Graphic Styles palette through Window > Graphic Styles;
Select one of the objects you applied the above effect on;
Drag said object directly into the Graphic Styles Palette;
Select another object;
Click the new miniature that appeared in the Graphic Styles palette.


It's easy in Inkscape, so get a copy for USD 0,-
There your text block can get path effect Perspective Envelope. Text unfortunately cannot be live, it must be converted to paths by applying at first Path > Object to path.
The corners of the envelope can be moved with the node tool. They snap to your gridline crossings if your grid is a bunch of rotated lines and you have node snapping option "snap to path crossings" ON. In Inkscape you can also define in document settings your custom grid angles if the standard ones are not OK. Then you can put snap to grid ON and the envelope corners snap to gridlines and grid crossings.
Expand the perspective envelope effect by applying Path > Object to path before saving your SVG. Inkscape's path effects are not available in other programs.
In the next image the corners of the perspective envelope are moved on your screenshot:

You can also do the same in Illustrator, except adjusting the envelope is difficult. As a bonus the text stays editable.
In Illustrator write a text block. Draw a rectangle. Adjust its corner nodes with the white arrow to fit to your grid. Use the modified rectangle as the top object when you apply Object > Envelope distort > Make with top object.
You can in theory edit the envelope with the white arrow, but you make it very easily curved, so it's best to release the envelope distortion, make a new envelope rectangle and delete the released envelope. The released envelope is a mesh which has curvature handles in corners which make editing tricky.
